# Imagemagick - Getting the usable dimension of an image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've a process which is creating a file with convert (ImageMagick) based on some parameter, and after that it checks the file and gives back the biggest dimension of it which has real pixels.

The commands look like this:

```
convert -size 5000x5000 xc:white -font {font} -pointsize {size} -fill black -draw "{some_occassional_additional_parameter}text 200,2500 \"{text}\"" {some_other_occassional_additional_parameter}{temporary_file}
convert {temporary_file}.png -trim +repage -format "%[w]x%[h]\n" info:
```

. It'll result something like: 526x425

This process runs half a million time per day, and it seems to be a huge bottleneck. I'm looking for a solution which can done this in memory, so not always creating a file and check it, but do it in memory somehow.

If can speed it up just like 50%, that'd be a huge achievement.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at a computer to test, but change your first command to:

```
convert -size ... xc:... occasionalstuff  -format "%@" info:
```

---

Note that you can, and probably should double quote the `"%@"` especially if you use expressions containing characters of significance to the shell, though it is not strictly necessary in this specific case.

Comment: On Linux/Mac OSX, use "%@" rather than %@. I believe that the double quotes are needed.

Comment: Cool. Very obvious, and very good answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you are doing half a million a day, you are likely parallel-processing or multi-processing. Your command needs 300MB of RAM, so it might be worth setting up a Q8 version of **ImageMagick** for this to halve the RAM demand and avoid swapping/thrashing - the quality is presumably irrelevant as it is just a sizing test you are doing rather than producing any critical output for which you could use the Q16 version.

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, I don't know of any need to double-quote that in `bash`, `sh` or `zsh` though it won't do any harm if you do.

Comment: I guess I needed to do it when it includes [...] and especially if spaces in their. So I just got in the habit of doing it for all string formats and fx expressions.